# Issues of persisting entity with relationship

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am using [nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/), [typeorm](https://typeorm.io/) and [nestjsx/crud](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud) to create API endpoints.

I have a user entity defined as follows:

```
@Entity({
    name: 'users'
})

export class User extends CommonEntity {

    @Column({ length: 104, unique: true })
    email: string;
    .
    .
    .

    @OneToOne(type => Role, role => role.user, { cascade: true, lazy: true })
    @JoinColumn()
    role: Role; //this creates a roleId column in user table
}
```

and a role entity:

```
@Entity({
    name: 'roles'
})

export class Role extends CommonEntity {

    @OneToOne(type => User, user => user.role)
    user: User;

    @Column({ length: 52 })
    name: string;

    @Column({ type: 'text' })
    policy: string;

}
```

How can a new user (with a role) be created via RESTful API using a single request?

I have attempted POSTing the following without success:

1. the below gives a duplicate record error. Apparently, it's attempting to create a new role record

```
{
  "email": "string03xyz@gmail.com",
  "role": {
    "id": "1f07f012-9391-4b5f-b6d3-574c58f4e046"
  }
}
```

2. roleId is ignored, nothing is added to the DB

```
{
  "email": "string03xyz@gmail.com",
  "roleId": "1f07f012-9391-4b5f-b6d3-574c58f4e046"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always going to claim that you are having a duplicated because it is a OneToOne Relation you need to use a ManyToMany Relation in which the ManyToMany relation is unique using a compound Id with the user Id and the role Id

Comment: I switched the relationship to OneToMany (one role to many users) because that's the logic that works for my app...and repeating the first attempt above worked. thanks